# EXT JS How to check field on form opening?

Tags: javascript, web, extjs

I have order form which contains combobox field. When user select specific value, system enables new set of fields in form.
This part of code looks like:

```
if (action.result.data.field == "1") {
     Order.query('fieldset[itemId="set1"]')[0].enable();
     Order.query('fieldset[itemId="set2"]')[0].show();
   }
```

But if user open editing form with already selected specific value, system doesn't show this set of fields. I need system to check specific value on opening the edit form. What class I should use?

Comment: How do you "open" the form, and how does your "form" look like - is it a in a window? If yes, you may want to check the `beforeshow` event on the window.

Comment: `Order.query('fieldset[itemId="set1"]')[0].enable();` -> `Order.down('#set1').enable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this ExtJS example. May be this can guide you. In your case, may be you have to listen to form.Panel render event and set the form fields based on the values in the record you got from server/present locally. Something like below.

```
 onSelectionChange: function(model, records) {
    var rec = records[0];
    if (rec) {
        this.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
    }
}
```

[load form based on record click](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#form-grid)